# How to generate xml documentation for asp.net website in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xml-documentation

I am trying generate XML comment for my asp.net website pages. But when i right click on the website in the solution explorer i can't find `Properties` instead i find `Propert Pages`. How to get started with xml documentation? Any suggestion.

More specifically here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azt1z1eh.aspx
("To build the XML Documentation sample within Visual Studio" section)

I want to generate XML comments for my project in the build, but my "Configuration Properties" window does not have "folders" or a "Build" option under it.

Answer (score -1):

It is not quite as convenient for Web Projects.  You need to manually add a "compiler" to your web.config.

http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/94c7f744-9b90-4254-93ab-9b15f47d9f42.htm