# Website project: want to generate XML documentation on build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project, xml-documentation

For legacy reasons, I'm maintaining a Web Site Project for which I want to provide up-to-date documentation from the XML documentation comments. I gather I can do that by tweaking the `<compilers>` section in `web.config`. I finally reached this point:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler
        language="c#;cs;csharp"
        extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider"
        compilerOptions="/optimize /doc:C:\temp\my-output-here.xml"
        warningLevel="1" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Now when I start the website with  (and thus invoke just-in-time compilation) I do get an XML file in the requested location but it's minimal:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>App_global.asax.abqhzva4</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
    </members>
</doc>
```

It seems like the `<compiler>` tag doesn't quite do what I want. It must be generating XML for the project folder itself rather than the `.cs` files, or it's getting overwritten with each compilation unit and I'm only seeing the trivial last one, or... I don't know. I'm not sure. This config tag is not well documented.

Long story short, I'm looking for a way to get XML documentation for all the `.cs` files in this website project. It doesn't matter if it's all in one file, in separate files, or even shoved into memory at run time.

I'm [aware of the prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863478/how-to-generate-xml-documentation-for-asp-net-website-in-visual-studio-2008) on this, but the link provided there has been redirected to the Sandcastle site. That's great, but it's way more than I'm actually going to use on this project. Simply getting XML documentation at build time or run time is all that is necessary.

My question then is: What do I need to do to get the `<compiler>` config entry to generate XML docs for a Website Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an ugly workaround as well... But here goes!

**1.** Download the latest Sandcastle Installer from this page - https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases

**2.** Unzip and run the installer

**3.** Copy `EWSoftware.CodeDom.dll` into your website's `\bin` directory.  The default location of this file is - `C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Extras\EWSoftware.CodeDom.dll`

**4.** Modify web.config as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        compilerOptions="/docpath:C:\Publish\Docs"
        type="EWSoftware.CodeDom.CSharpCodeProviderWithDocs, EWSoftware.CodeDom"
      >
        <!-- NOTE: Change version value as needed (v3.5, v4.0, etc.) -->
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Source: http://ewsoftware.github.io/EWSoftwareCodeDom/html/40ba6bda-95d6-4a64-834f-f7cedcb589d1.htm

**5.** Rebuild your solution and voila!  The folder specified with the `/docpath` option will contain your XML documentation.

Comment: I like this! Sure, it means installing all of Sandcastle, but the result is pretty low-maintenance. Good one.

Comment: Thanks :). I have a hunch that each directory is built with a new call to csc.exe.  Using your original technique, as each folder is built, the output XML file overwrites the previous folder's XML file.  So all that you see is the XML file of the last folder that was compiled.  Hence the need for the Sandcastle compiler, which gives each folder a uniquely named XML file.

Comment: Or perhaps a call to csc.exe is made for each file?  The point being if multiple calls are made, you need a way to specify a destination XML file for each call.