# Where to specify the /doc switch in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, documentation

To generate an XML documentation file I need to add the `/doc` or `-doc` switch to the build options.  I cannot work out where to add this.  I am using (an updated this morning) Visual Studio 17 Community Edition.  The Solution is slightly older, 2015, as you can see in the file pasted below.  Below are  screenshots of the windows in vs2017 that would be the appropriate place to hide this setting.

**Project Properties**

[image: Project Properties]

**Solution Properties**

[image: Solution Properties]

**Solution File**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26430.16
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
          XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Project("{XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}") = "Anchor", "http://localhost:9637", "{XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_9637"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\Anchor\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_9637\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_9637"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\WebSites\Anchor\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_9637\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\WebSites\Anchor\"
        DefaultWebSiteLanguage = "Visual C#"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{C24735CF-C0CF-4FF2-AABE-0A1EDD678318}"
EndProject
Project("{00D1A9C2-B5F0-4AF3-8072-F6C62B433612}") = "AnchorDb", "AnchorDb\AnchorDb.sqlproj", "{722FE50A-126F-41E6-AC1C-126303A5C131}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {XXXXXXXX-YYYY-XXXX-YYYY-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        VisualSVNWorkingCopyRoot = ..\..\WebSites\Anchor
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where to specify the /doc switch in Visual Studio 2017

According to the official document [Documenting your code with XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) and [/doc (Process Documentation Comments) (C/C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501.aspx):

> If you are developing an application using Visual Studio, right-click on the project and select **Properties**. In the properties dialog, select the **Build** tab, and check **XML documentation file**. You can also change the location to which the compiler writes the file.
>
> If you are compiling a .NET Framework application from the command line, add the **/doc** compiler option when compiling.

For C++ project:

> Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
>
> Expand the Configuration Properties node.
>
> Expand the C/C++ node. Select the Output Files property page.
>
> Modify the Generate XML Documentation Files property.

**However**, I noticed that you are using **website project**, it looks there is no "**direct**" option for websites unlike web application projects. There are few tools [vsdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html),[SandCastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases) which you can generate the final documentation and the XML file even from a website project.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656604/website-project-want-to-generate-xml-documentation-on-build) for some more details.